# Windows 10 Upgrade Error c1900101 30018

Tags: windows-10-upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade from windows 8.1 to windows 10 on my Dell XPS
I keep getting error c1900101-30018
It just hangs on 32% (main) + 6% (sub)
Apparently this is when it is installing drivers.

Is there anywhere on my PC I can find a log and see what driver it is failing on.
I've also disconnected all my usb devices etc... before trying the update as some people where suggesting that on google searches for this error.

I've also tried upgrading a number of times and still same error.
I'm using windows update to do this (not the ISO, as I don't have a flash drive / cd drive handy).

Comment: [Find your error code on this page](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/wiki/insider_wintp-insider_install/how-to-troubleshoot-common-setup-and-stop-errors/324d5a5f-d658-456c-bb82-b1201f735683)

Answer (score 2):

#### Windows 10 Upgrade Error c1900101 30018

> - Disable (preferably uninstall) your Antivirus utility before attempting the upgrade.
> - Restart a few times and try again.
> - Disable General USB Devices (example - Smart Card Reader).
> - If you are using a SCSI hard disk, make sure you have drivers available for your storage device on a thumdrive and it is connected.
>     During Windows 10 setup, click the Custom Advanced Option and use the
>     Load Driver command to load the appropriate driver for the SCSI drive.
>     If this does not work and setup still fails, consider switching to a
>     IDE based hard disk.
> - Do a clean boot and try again.
> - If you are upgrading using the .ISO file, disconnect from the Internet during setup, if you are connected by LAN (Ethernet) or
>     Wi-Fi, disable both and attempt setup again.
> - If you are updating through Windows Update, when the download reaches 100% disconnect from the Internet LAN (Ethernet) or Wi-Fi and
>     proceed with the installation.
> - If that does not work, try using the .ISO file to upgrade if possible.
> - If you are connected to a domain, switch to a local account
> - If you have any external devices attached to the machine, disconnect them (example, gaming controllers, USB keys, external hard
>     disk, printers, non-essential devices).
>
> [How to: upgrade from previous versions of Windows using Windows 10
>   ISO file](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/wiki/insider_wintp-insider_install/how-to-upgrade-from-previous-versions-of-windows/31722b30-1da9-42bb-b331-0edc4649bf43)
>
> [How to download official Windows 10 ISO files](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wiki/windows_10-windows_install/how-to-download-official-windows-10-iso-files/35cde7ec-5b6f-481c-a02d-dadf465df326)
>
> **If you are installing Windows 10 using Windows Update, try the following:**
>
> 1. Press Windows Key + X on the keyboard and then select “Command Prompt (Admin)” from the menu.
> 2. Stop the BITS, Cryptographic, MSI Installer and the Windows Update Services. To do this, type the following commands at a command prompt.
>      Press the “ENTER” key after you type each command.
>
>    ```
>    net stop wuauserv
>    net stop cryptSvc
>    net stop bits
>    net stop msiserver
>    ```
> 3. Now rename the SoftwareDistribution and Catroot2 folder. You can do this by typing the following commands in the Command Prompt. Press the
>      “ENTER” key after you type each command.
>
>    ```
>    ren C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution SoftwareDistribution.old
>    ren C:\Windows\System32\catroot2 Catroot2.old
>    ```
> 4. Now, let’s restart the BITS, Cryptographic, MSI Installer and the Windows Update Services. Typethe following commands in the Command
>      Prompt for this. Press the ENTER key after you type each command.
>
>    ```
>    net start wuauserv
>    net start cryptSvc
>    net start bits
>    net start msiserver
>    ```
> 5. Type Exit in the Command Prompt to close it and then restart the computer.

Source [How to: Troubleshoot common Setup and Stop Errors during Windows 10 Installation](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/wiki/insider_wintp-insider_install/how-to-troubleshoot-common-setup-and-stop-errors/324d5a5f-d658-456c-bb82-b1201f735683)

Comment: I'm going to try the flash drive ISO update tomorrow when I get into the office.

Comment: @DermFrench Did you mange to resolve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are upgrading through your 'reserved' free copy or by selecting "upgrade now" on the Windows 10 Media Creation Tool.

I too when upgrading one of my computers got an error like that and what solved it was the following:

1. Download the **[Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)**, if you haven't already
2. Run the Tool & Select "Create installation media for another PC" NOT Upgrade this PC now[image]
3. Select language, edition, and architecture that applies to you
4. Select "USB Flash Drive", click next and choose your drive [image]
5. Once the setup finishes, go to your computer and open the flash drive you choose and run "**setup.exe**".

Comment: "I don't have a flash drive / cd drive handy"

Comment: He edited his post to say that after the fact, so thanks for that -1

Comment: So what is stopping you from editing your answer so its relevant to the current revision of the question?

Comment: If you didn't notice he edited his post then I didn't either. So what's stopping me? _Time_, at the moment.

Comment: So don't complain about the downvote.  I can't do anything about the vote until the answer is edited.  I almost don't want to do anything because of your attitude over a single downvote.

Comment: I ended up having to do this from office with a flash drive, worked first time, so I'm not sure the question is going to get an answer now (since I edited).

Comment: I'm confused, since you did this is the question answered? Just edit your question to remove you don't have a flash drive since you found one

Comment: Ok so this worked on one dell with the iso update however on another dell exact same error on ISO (with update via windows update both got same error with ISO only one got error other succeeded argggggghhhh)

Comment: Interesting why one would work and the other wouldn't. Next recommendation would be to reinstall Windows 8.1 then try to do the upgrade the same way.

Comment: Wonder are Microsoft addressing this, and would future upgrade downloads maybe work? I've already refreshed windows 8.1 on this PC that won't work and tried that and again no joy. I've been trying different things every night for about a week.

Comment: I wouldn't refresh I would backup all personal files, do a clean install of 8.1, and then do an upgrade. You'll be guaranteed a fresh install that way. It might not be the solution you're after but that's all I can think of :(

Comment: I think I'll stick with 8.1 for a while, see if Microsoft resolves this themselves.